# How to escape '-' (minus) with Regex? C#

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

So I'm using C# Regex.Escape() to escape all of the characters inside so that I can match words accordingly, however, Regex.Escape() doesn't seem to escape the '-' character, what should I do?

```
        string punctuation = ",. ?-!;";
        string pattern = String.Format("([^{0}]+)([{0}]+)", Regex.Escape(punctuation));
        Console.WriteLine(pattern);
```

This is the code that I tried, it outputs:
([^,\.\ \?-!;]+)([,\.\ \?-!;]+)

What I want it to output is :
([^,\.\ \?\-!;]+)([,\.\ \?\-!;]+)

I want there to be a '\' before the '-', what should I do?

Comment: Because it only escapes the chars that should be escaped *outside* of character classes. Use  `punctuation.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("-", @"\-").Replace("^", @"\^").Replace("]", @"\]")` instead.

Comment: Add the hyphen `-` as the last char, that will resolve your issue, since a hyphen does not need to be escaped when last  in character class.